# How to Translate I'm not a robot Title of powermailrecaptcha to another language in TYPO3 v10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail

I have integrated The extension "powermailrecaptcha" to the powermail form in one of my TYPO3 websites.
The output contains the title  "I'm not a robot" In English. I want to Display it in the German Language.[captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vj7I.png)

How to do this? Any Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not labeled from powermail, it's google ReCaptcha. But, you can find some way from Developer guide here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es">
```

You can pass language argument to Recaptcha.For more, check out the configuration settings here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Hmm Okay, I will try.